# Different behaviors of 'is' operator when comparing variables with same int values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm playing with the *'is'* operator in the interactive shell when I encountered an odd behavior with the below code:

It goes as expected at first:

```
>>> x = 11

>>> y = 11

>>> x is y

True
```

But when I tried this one:

```
>>> x = 987456

>>> y = 987456

>>> x is y

False
```

After further tries using id() function, I noticed that integers >256 points on the same object while others are not. I also noticed that this behavior only occurs in the python interactive shell. What's with this behavior?

Comment: @PeterWood As I mentioned I was just playing with it then I encountered that odd behavior

Answer (score -1):

`is` checks for memory address. Immutable objects that are wrappers around `C` type tends to have same memory address, whereas others don't. The difference here is the bytes required to store the integers.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, since you also need to explain why the memory address may be the same for small integers, but not for large ones. However, this is a duplicate so user can look up previous answers.

Comment: I cannot find a single trace of `==` in the question.

Comment: The behaviour of `is` is an optimisation issue, not to do with wrappers around `C` types.